# Making faces with vertices

Tags: vertices, faces

When I want to create the faces between bottom of the handle and the body with manner that you select vertices and make faces, I get a problem that when I want to select the last vertices, the hole vertical vertices of that point get selected as you can see.

[image]

Comment: Probably you selected wrong edge loop and your aim was to select the opened one at the end of the handle. In that case move the mouse cursor more towards the center of one of edges of that opened loop while Alt+ left clicking.

Answer (score 1):

The vertices you selected can only be selected when you press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>LMB</kbd> so you might've accidentally pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd> while selecting the vertex. To select multiple vertices, you need to select one vertex, press and hold <kbd>Shift</kbd>, select next vertex, and so on.